# Mobile Service Configuration: MS_NotificationHubConnectionString Contains Invalid Setting Key "entitypath"

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to create a new Azure Mobile Service, however when trying to call a Custom API it generates the following error in the logs of the service.

> An error occurred creating push for user scripts:
>   azure.notificationHubService could not be created.  HubName:
>   "servicenamehub"  ConnectionString
>   "Endpoint=sb://servicenamehub-ns.servicebus.windows.net/;
>   SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;
>   SharedAccessKey={accesskey};EntityPath=servicenamehub": Error from
>   create-Error: Invalid connection string setting key "entitypath".

The error only seems to generate when making an API call, not when making a call on a table.

The `MS_NotificationHubConnectionString` is where this connection string is stored, however it was auto generated along with the service hub and isn't editable in the service configuration.

The EntityPath key doesn't appear in the `MS_NotificationHubConnectionString` of any of my older services. The Mobile Service has a JavaScript back end.

How do I prevent this error or remove the EntityPath key from the connection string?

Comment: Can you share the code from the custom API?

Comment: Also, is this Azure Mobile Service or Azure Mobile Apps? (classic or new portal)?

Comment: It happens when using the default code or custom code, on both GET and POST. It's Mobile Services in classic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, here is a workaround: we login Kudu console site of the Mobile Service backend, modify `MS_NotificationHubConnectionString` in the script which will create notification hub service directly in source code.

1. login in Kudu console site, whose url should be `https://<your_mobile_service_name>.scm.azure-mobile.net/DebugConsole`
2. In the file system list in the page, enter to the path `D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\azure-mobile-services\runtime\push`, edit the file `pushadapter.js`
3. Add following code to the start of the function `PushAdapter` in this script around line 22:

   `var string = options.MS_NotificationHubConnectionString;
    var index = string.indexOf('EntityPath');
       options.MS_NotificationHubConnectionString = index>0?string.slice(0,string.indexOf('EntityPath')-1):string;`

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.